# Event when marker location changes in Google Maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-handling, google-maps-markers

I can't figure out how can I handle Google Maps marker changes.

Ideally, I want to get marker location changes in real-time.

Finally, I've [checked the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#MarkerEvents) and I didn't find an specific event to cover this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an easy one:

```
marker.addListener("dragend", e => {
   // Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: does not get fired when setposition is called on marker.